# How to disable adding automatically spaces (e.g.in the if condition line) in VS17

Tags: visual-studio, code-formatting

I'm using VS17 and I would like to change my coding settings so that VS stops adding spaces at e.g. if conditions in language C. I searched for enabling this option but unfortunaly I could find a formatting option.

So please help me :)

What I'm coding and what it should like afterwards:

```
if(varA == varB){}
```

What it looks like after I close the second }. VS is adding single spaces after if and between ) and {

```
if (varA == varB) {}
```

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings are language specific, and are under Text Editor in the Tools / Options dialog.

For C# for example, unchecking "*insert space after keywords in control flow statements*" in Text Editor / C# / Code Style / Formatting / Spacing turns off the automatic space after `if`, `for` etc.

[image]

For C/C++ a similar setting exists under Text Editor / C/C++ / Code Style / Formatting / Spacing "*insert space between keyword and opening parenthesis in control flow statements*".

Comment: Thanks dxiv ! It worked fine for me. Only your shared path is a little bit different to mine (Text Editor/C/C++/Formatting/Spacing). So there is no "Code Style" object.

Comment: @HKC72 Glad it helped. I did not realize the "*code style*" was added into VS19, and didn't have a VS17 at hand to check.

Comment: That explains it :)